# Populating a php array without specifying all elements when the elements are identical

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create an array like this `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

In python I can use `myarray = [1]*5`

Is there an equivalent method in PHP or I have to add all the elements in a loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php

```
<?php

var_dump( array_fill( 0, 5, 1 ) );

?>
```

Comment: Start index could be probably 0 and not 1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

what you need is array_fill

see [php array_fill](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_fill.asp)